# Entity Framework not including columns with default value in insert into query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a model that has some columns defined with default values like

```
table.Column<bool>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "1")
```

When I save a new entity in the database using `context.SaveChanges()`, I noticed that the columns with default values are not included in the insert into query that Entity Framework generates, so the values generated in the database are the default ones instead of the ones I'm passing in the model.

Do I have to set up some property in the context to be able to set these properties through code? I'm using EF Core, but I don't know if this is a general behavior of all EF versions.

UPDATE: the code is pretty simple. This is pseudo code of what I have.
The Model has some properties defined with constraints such as the one I describe above 
`table.Column<bool>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "1")`

I'll use column MyBooleanProperty as an example. I have in a service:

```
var newModel = new GEAddress();
newModel = someEntity.MyBooleanProperty; //it is false,but ends up as 1 in the database
```

I'm using Unit Of Work and Repositories so I have

```
_unitOfWork.MyModelRepository.Add(newModel);
_unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

In the output window of VS, I see how it send all properties in an `INSERT INTO` query and then it does a `SELECT` on the properties with default values. The result is the newModel in the database with all the values I sent, except the columns with default values.
I cannot change the configuration for those tables since it's being used by another system that needs those rules.

I would like to know an explanation on why this is happening more than a solution. I can work around this, but I'd like to know why this behavior is happening

Comment: General behavior is "The default value of a column is the value that will be inserted if a new row is inserted but no value is specified for the column."

In your case looks like you are losing the values that are set. can you post your code?

Comment: FWIW, EF6 does not support Default Values - you must explicitly specify a value for all columns, even if a non-`NULL` column has an explicit default-value set.

Comment: In that case you can remove the configuration for your column to disable default values behavior, in that way the default value will provide by database. Can you show your code (DbContext, Mappings, Pocos) ?

Comment: Please show how you mapped the property. If it is queried after an insert is must have been mapped as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`.

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Comment: By * I cannot change the configuration for those tables* do you mean you cannot change the database table definition or you cannot change the dbcontext configuration in your system?

Comment: @GertArnold, this is the mapping of the property `entity.Property(e => e.ShowAddressOnWeb).HasDefaultValueSql("1")` . The model doesn't have any annotations and in the database it is not a computed field.

Comment: @ErikEJ, EF 1.0

Comment: Maybe you should try 1.1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with EF Core 5 HasDefaultValue, ef pushes default value when value is set to the .Net type default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769871/issue-with-ef-core-5-hasdefaultvalue-ef-pushes-default-value-when-value-is-set)

Comment: Though hidden, the behavior is documented now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/miscellaneous#working-with-default-values

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would call this a bug.

I snapped together a simple test, just a class with some defaults:

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IntDef { get; set; }
    public bool BoolDef { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDef { get; set; }
}
```

(Note that the DateTime is nullable)

The mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasKey(a => a.ID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(s => s.DateDef).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(s => s.IntDef).HasDefaultValueSql("1");
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(s => s.BoolDef).HasDefaultValue(true);
// Equivalent:
// modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(s => s.BoolDef).HasDefaultValueSql("1");
```

SQL statement that creates the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Tests] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [BoolDef] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    [DateDef] datetime2 DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    [IntDef] int NOT NULL DEFAULT (1),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tests] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
);
```

When I insert a new `Test` without setting any value, the insert statement is:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Tests]
DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT [ID], [BoolDef], [DateDef], [IntDef]
FROM [Tests]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = scope_identity();
```

You see that the three default values (and the generated identity value) are read from the database after the insert. [By the way, this is new in EF-Core. In EF6, only identity values and column values that were marked as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` were read from the database after insert (and update)].

This is the created `Test` object:

```sql
ID IntDef BoolDef DateDef
1  1      True    21-11-16 19:52:56
```

Now I insert a new `Test` and assign all values, but, just for fun, I use the default values for the non-nullable types:

```cs
var item = new Test
{ 
    IntDef = default(int), // 0 
    BoolDef = default(bool), // false
    DateDef = default(DateTime), // 01-01-01 0:00:00
};
```

Here's the SQL statement:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Tests] ([DateDef])
VALUES (@p0);
SELECT [ID], [BoolDef], [IntDef]
FROM [Tests]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = scope_identity();
',N'@p0 datetime2(7)',@p0='0001-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Of course, EF has no way to infer that the default values were assigned deliberately. So as you see, only for the nullable `DateTime` column the assigned value is inserted, not for the non-nullable columns. Now the value for `DateDef` isn't read from the database after the insert.

The entity values are:

```sql
ID IntDef BoolDef DateDef
1  1      True    01-01-01 0:00:00
```

Not what one would expect after saving the entity --not at all!

Which means:

When you configure a property with a default value in EF-Core, and this default is different than the .Net default value, **you can't insert an entity with default values for the .Net type** (like `false` for a boolean).

I think this is a serious bug, maybe it even disqualifies the new EF-Core behaviour concerning defaults.

**Addition**
As said in Ivan's comment, you can stop EF from setting default values for you by adding `ValueGeneratedNever()`, for example:

```sql
modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().Property(s => s.IntDef)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("1").ValueGeneratedNever();
```

Now the value will be saved as it is and EF won't read it back after inserts and updates. All in all, I think defining defaults for non-nullable properties isn't useful.

---

It seems that this is finally [solved in EF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#boolean-columns-with-a-database-generated-value-are-no-longer-scaffolded-as-nullable) (didn't test it yet).

Comment: I'll mark this as answer since it confirms that indeed there's something wrong with that behavior. thanks!

Comment: Just to add that currently there is no way to control that behavior dynamically at runtime. All you can do is to turn it off statically using `ValueGeneratedNever()`.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, didn't know this one yet. I think we can prepare for tons of questions coming in at SO concerning this behavior.

Comment: I posted the issue in github and it seems you have to define the properties as nullable so the CLR will know when to assignthe value you're passing. I haven't tested all cases, but here is the link https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7089

Comment: @monica I would suggest you submitting enhancement request. For instance, setting `PropertyEntry.IsModified` to `true` for a new object, or considering `DefaultValue` attribute on property/field etc.

Comment: Wow you are a godsend. your comment about DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed was the answer for me. Unbelievable.

Comment: This remains a problem with EF Core 6.

Comment: @CPerkins Yep, although `.HasDefaultValueSql(...).ValueGeneratedNever()` is a reasonable work-around.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mark the property as computed with the proper attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

ef will generate the insert statement with the property value.
During update EF generates the UPDATE statement SET clause inserting only changed values.

You have already a workaround anyway, if the property is only generated by the DBMS you can use the attribute above otherwise you have to insert the default value in the constructor of the class that rapresent the entity.

Comment: `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` indicates a column whose value will always be provided by the database, causing EF to ignore updates on that column from user code. The OP only wants to provide a default value to be used when a value is not specified, but to be able to specify it upon insertion or modification.

Comment: I agree with @bubi, I have other columns with that attribute and they work fine. My issue is the ones with default values that are not getting the inserted valu

Comment: @CodeCaster the problem is that the concept *not specified* for EF does not exist (exists the concept _changed_ for the tracked entities) so if you don't specify `Computed` EF will always generate the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueGeneratedNever` didn't do the job for me (Entity Framework Core 3.1.21). I simply deleted `.HasDefaultValueSql` from DBContext and leaved default value in database schema. Works fine, maybe this note can be useful for somebody

Comment: I'm using EF Core 6 with code-first migrations.  After adding `ValueGeneratedNever` to the affected columns in `DBContext.OnModelCreating()`, I updated the migrations.  Although the new migration itself was blank--no change to the database, it did update the `*DbContextModelSnapshot.cs` to match the change to the columns.  Tests reveal that this resolved the problem without changing the `HasDefaultValueSql` calls.