# EF Core 2.0 - System.NotSupportedException On Add

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.0.  I have a table with 4 columns where the PK is made up of all 4 columns.  One of the columns (IsDefault) is a bit field in the database.  If I insert a record with IsDefault set to true everything works fine.  If I insert a record with IsDefault set to false I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException occurred
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=The 'IsDefault' on entity type 'ChromeMileageRestrictionTest' does not have a value set and no value generator is available for properties of type 'bool'. Either set a value for the property before adding the entity or configure a value generator for properties of type 'bool'.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGeneratorSelector.Create(IProperty property, IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.RelationalValueGeneratorSelector.Create(IProperty property, IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.Internal.SqlServerValueGeneratorSelector.Create(IProperty property, IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGeneratorSelector.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Select>b__0(IProperty p, IEntityType e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGeneratorCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__3_0(CacheKey ck)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGeneratorCache.GetOrAdd(IProperty property, IEntityType entityType, Func`3 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGeneratorSelector.Select(IProperty property, IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.Internal.SqlServerValueGeneratorSelector.Select(IProperty property, IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.ValueGenerationManager.Generate(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState entityState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Add[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at DAL.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\Users\jkruer\Source\Repos\JLM.App.ChromeIncentivesService\DAL.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 12
```

I created a VERY simplified version and am able to reproduce the problem with my single table, single entity, single record, single unit test implementation.

My Database Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChromeMileageRestrictionTEST](
    [TermID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Mileage] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Residual] [decimal](18, 8) NOT NULL,
    [isDefault] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ChromeMileageRestrictionTEST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TermID] ASC,
    [Mileage] ASC,
    [Residual] ASC,
    [isDefault] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChromeMileageRestrictionTEST] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ChromeMileageRestrictionTEST_Residual]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Residual]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChromeMileageRestrictionTEST] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ChromeMileageRestrictionTEST_isDefault]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [isDefault]
GO
```

My dbContext:

```
public partial class ReportingContext : DbContext
    {
        public ReportingContext()
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ChromeMileageRestrictionTest> ChromeMileageRestriction { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"MyConnectionStringGoesHere");            
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChromeMileageRestrictionTest>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.TermId, e.Mileage, e.Residual, e.IsDefault })                
                .HasName("PK_ChromeMileageRestrictionTest");

                entity.Property(e => e.TermId)
                    .HasColumnName("TermID")
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Mileage)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Residual)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 8)")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");

                entity.Property(e => e.IsDefault)
                    .HasColumnName("isDefault")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
            });
        }
    }
```

My Entity:

```
public partial class ChromeMileageRestrictionTest
    {
        public string TermId { get; set; }
        public string Mileage { get; set; }
        public decimal Residual { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    }
```

My Unit Test:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var dbContext = new ReportingContext();
            dbContext.Add(new ChromeMileageRestrictionTest 
            {
                TermId = "6078915-0-0",
                Mileage = "15,000",
                Residual = 45.00000000M,
                IsDefault = true //THIS WORKS
            });
            dbContext.Add(new ChromeMileageRestrictionTest 
            {
                TermId = "6078915-0-0",
                Mileage = "15,000",
                Residual = 45.00000000M,
                IsDefault = false //THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION
            });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I've been scratching my head on this one for a while.  I can't figure it out.  Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested, just for the sake of it, to change the type in `ChromeMileageRestrictionTest` to a `byte` and insert 1 or 0 in the bit column? Since you only have one bit field - you could also try using a `tinyint` field in the database instead.

Comment: you are adding the same record twice, it appears so.  try editing some of that data so that its not all the same.  if your PK is on all of those columns then shouldn't they be unique?  I think your error is a false positive and the real underlying issue is that this data you are writing is not unique and it needs to be

Comment: you are also adding two records, try adding one and save it and then add the next and save it. so two SaveChanges instead of one

Comment: @fredrik isn't the standard convention for EntityFramework to use a bool property and a bit field in the database? I don't think I fully understand your suggestion.

Comment: @Aaron.S the primary key is across all 4 columns.  One of the record has true and the other record has false so they are unique.  Even if I delete the first entry the 2nd entry still fails.  Also, the exception is thrown before the SaveChanges() is ever called.  The exception gets thrown on the call to dbContext.Add()

Comment: basic save https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic dbContext.ChromeMileageRestrictionTests.Add(new{ TermId = "6078915-0-0", Mileage = "15,000",Residual = 45.00000000M,IsDefault = false });  isn't this the proper way to add ONE record to the many in the context?

Comment: it appears as if you are missing dbContext.SOMETHINGHERE.Add(...);

Comment: See this:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7163 It's a much debated issue. I don't understand EF's course here. Or this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8540

Comment: OK: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40619319/861716) is the duplicate I was looking for. Please see if you can live with it and mark your question as duplicate.

Comment: Wow! @GertArnold That is crazy! I'm testing this solutions to see if it works correctly or not.  Once I verify I will do that. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: It works of course. The question is why ever have that `HasDefaultValueSql` at all. Just unnecessary db trips, has to back them all with `ValueGeneratedNever`.

Comment: @IvanStoev the IsDefault column was added to the existing table when there was already records in it.  Since the field in non-nullable a default value was provided for all of the existing records.  When we scaffolded the dbcontext, the scaffolding added the HasDefaultValueSql to the dbContext.

Comment: Well, this sounds like temporary workaround to get the new columns created. It should have been removed after. Anyway, you can simply remove the generated `HasDefaultValueSql` from both properties or add `ValueGeneratedNever` to both properties. It doesn't really matter since if you re-scaffold you'd probably lose your adjustments anyway.

Comment: @jkruer01 It wasn't meant as a solution - rather a means of debugging.

Comment: Closed as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40619319/213550

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of this: [Entity Framework not including columns with default value in insert into query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619319/entity-framework-not-including-columns-with-default-value-in-insert-into-query)

TLDR: I removed the default value of False on the IsDefault field both from the database and from the DbContext mapping.  This solved the problem.