# Why is Entity Framework resetting my enum to default value when saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am debugging the following baffling behaviour. I have an entity `ExampleEntity` which contains a `[Required]` enum, which for migration reasons, has a default value. When inserting a new `ExampleEntity`, I am specifying the value this field should take. Inspecting in the debugger reveals the value has been set correctly in the local version of the `DbSet`. However, whenever I call `SaveChanges()` on the context, the enums value is reset to the configured default value.

The models:

```
public enum ExampleEnum
{
    Mecury,
    Venus,
    Earth,
    Mars
}

internal class ExampleEntity
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ExampleEnum Val { get; set; }
}

internal class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ExampleEntity> Ents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<ExampleEntity>(entity =>
       {
            entity.Property(e => e.Val).HasDefaultValue(ExampleEnum.Earth);
       });
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
class Program
{
    private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EFContext>()
                .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                .Options;

        using (var context = new EFContext(ContextOptions))
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        using (var db = new EFContext(ContextOptions))
        {
            var newEntity = new ExampleEntity
            {
               Val = ExampleEnum.Mecury,
            };
            db.Ents.Add(newEntity);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var db = new EFContext(ContextOptions))
        {
            var savedEnt = db.Ents.First();
            Console.WriteLine(savedEnt.Val.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the value printed to be `Mercury` but it prints out the configured default `Earth`. I can resolve this by after saving the changes, setting the `Val` to be the desired value:

```
var newEntity = new ExampleEntity
{
   Val = ExampleEnum.Mecury,
};
db.Ents.Add(newEntity);
db.SaveChanges();
newEnttity.Val = ExampleEnum.Mecury;
db.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Releated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40619319/861716

Answer (score 2):

The issue was caused by using the default value of Mecury (0). Entity Framework presumably is unable to tell the difference between an uninitialized enum and one purposefully set to 0, so it assumes the former and sets the default.

Probably the simplest fix is to use zero (first enum value) as the default. In this case, reordering the enum to be:

```
Earth
Mecury
Venus
Mars
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-ordering the enum which would create a bit of an issue the minute you go and decide to change the default one in code then end up with invalidating existing data. Instead, I would recommend always using a NotSet/None default for declared enumerations:

```
public enum ExampleEnum
{
    NotSet = 0,
    Mecury,
    Venus,
    Earth,
    Mars
}
```

For Entities I would recommend setting defaults on your entity properties. This way new entities are initialized and in a valid state prior to, and after being persisted:

```
internal class ExampleEntity
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ExampleEnum Val { get; set; } = ExampleEnum.Earth;
}
```

`HasDefaultValue` just tells EF to expect a DefaultValue to be set on the column when a value isn't provided. Where CodeFirst is applied, the value you specify is what the default would be set to. It does appear to introduce a blocker to update the property to a default value of (0) given removing that `HasDefaultValue` configuration will allow you to save the original Mercury (0) value with a new row. I was testing this with and without the configuration using:

```
var test = new ExampleEntity { Val = ExampleEnum.Mars};
test.Val = ExampleEnum.Mercury;
```

Which eliminated EF ignoring the "set" because the class default for the enum was still (0 [Mercury]). With your configuration and enum declaration with Mercury = 0 the above test still failed for the same reason. Removing the configuration for the default and the above set worked as expected.

All up I would recommend setting the enum default to something like "NotSet" then also use initializers on your properties for desired defaults where EF just worries about the underlying schema.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same exact problem today. We had an enum that is not nullable so it is required and the default value was defined in the entity configuration. For some cases, the value being passed to the DbContext was not persisting and defaults to the `Enum.Default`. Me and my colleagues were baffled by this behavior. It also became that one enum column was affecting the value of another enum column but I won't get into much details about it.

`builder.Property(_ => _.MyEnum).HasDefaultValue(Enum.Default).HasConversion<string>();`

What worked for us is that we added a new migration after removing the default value. This fixed all our enum issues.

`builder.Property(_ => _.MyEnum).HasConversion<string>();`

We originally needed the default value to apply to existing records for the new column but since Code First Migrations run consecutively, when the first migration runs it adds the default value to existing records and then we remove the default since moving forward it is a required property.