# Entity Framework Core 3.1.8 not saving 0 to column with default value of -1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a table with one integer column that is not a primary or foreign key. It has a default value of -1.

EF auto-generated code has this setup for the table.

```
entity.Property(e => e.ControlFlag)
    .HasColumnName("ControlFlag")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("((-1))");
```

When I set `ControlFlag=0` and add the row to the table by calling the EF Core `SaveChanges()` method, the column gets saved with -1.

If I set `ControlFlag=1`, the value saved in the column is 1.

Why does it not like to save 0?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619319/entity-framework-not-including-columns-with-default-value-in-insert-into-query/) that had similar issues.  Solution was essentially to stop EF from setting default values for you by adding ValueGeneratedNever()  Not sure why it's showing the behavior you described, and haven't had a chance to test this but seems like it may work.

Comment: that would mean that we have to edit the context file every time its regenerated.

Comment: You can create a partial class for the context that setups that `ValueGeneratedNever` that way you can regenerate the context whenever. Editing the context is something people need to do pretty often when you're doing db-first stuff in dotnet core.